# Multi-Conferencing with Opentok

Tags: opentok, tokbox

Is it possible to subscribe to more than one publishers using OpenTok.js? I have a requirement where more than two participants will be part of the conference.  Please let me know is there a way I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can subscribe to multiple publishers at the same time. You have to listen for the onStreamCreated event in the session, create a subscriber, and subscribe to the session with this newly created subscriber.
I hope this helps.